# Assign Variable with First Day of the Month

Tags: c#, vb.net, datetime

I have a program that I want to assign a variable the "first day of the month".  Here is what I have so far:

```
Dim dtToday As DateTime = DateTime.Today 'Sets todays date (04/15/13)
Dim dtYesterday As DateTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1) 'Sets Yesterdays Date (04/14/13)
```

I would like to Define "dtFirstOfMonth" next.  It would set the first of the month to "04/01/13"  This would change depending on the day it's run obviously...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim dtFirstOfMonth as DateTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1)
```

Comment: Great.  Could you explain how this assigns it the first of the month?

Comment: That's what the `1` is for - one of the constructors for `DateTime` is `(int year, int month, int day)`, so `(now.year, now.month, 1)` will get the first of this month. I believe that's what you're looking for, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can subtract current day of month from current date. Then add `1` to get first day:

```
var firstDayOfMonth = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1 - DateTime.Today.Day);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below, it will help you...

```
 Dim dtToday As DateTime = DateTime.Today
 Dim dtFrom As DateTime
 dtFrom = dtToday.AddDays(-(dtToday.Day - 1))
```